# Firebase date format match

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, date-format, firebase-security

How can I validate for a date format of type "September 28, 2017" with Firebase?
I have tried the below, but seems not to be correct:

```
".validate": "newData.isString() &&
                newData.val().matches(/^[\w\][\s]([0-3][0-9])[,\s](19|20)[0-9][0-9]$/)"
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Update:

As Firebaser Frank explains in his comment, the backslashes need to be escaped.  Making those changes to your rule with a few other minor corrections results in:

```
".validate": "newData.isString() &&
             newData.val().matches(/^[\\w]+[\\s][0-3][0-9][,][\\s](19|20)[0-9][0-9]$/)"
```

---

I used the rules simulator in the Firebase console to debug this.  When I pasted in your validation rule, the `\w` and `\s` were rejected as "invalid escapes".  I'm not sure why that is.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex#supported_features) indicates they should be accepted.  Were you able to successfully publish your rule with `\w` and `\s`?  I couldn't.

I made changes to work around that issue. I also changed `[,\s]` since in your example of `September 28, 2017` you have a space after the comma.

```
  ".validate": "newData.isString() &&
            newData.val().matches(/^[A-Z][a-z]+ [0-3][0-9], (19|20)[0-9][0-9]$/)"
```

Comment: You'll likely need double `\\` escapes. See the examples in https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex#usage

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen:  Ah yes!  I recall now your explanation of this on a previous question.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to update it but i have actually used "\/ w", because firebase errored out the first version. Ya, it's weird that the documentation says it can be used that way. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @dre_84w934:  See my update.  FvP explained that the backslashes need to be escaped.

Comment: @dre_84w934 the proper way to say thanks at SO is to use the check mark below the votes counter to mark the answer that solves your issue as correct.